# Sandcastle -> Output to HTML -> Import to MOSS utility

Tags: html, sharepoint, moss, sandcastle

I am about to write an import to MOSS utility from Sandcastle HTML output. Before I do this I would just like to ask if anyone knows of a tool that can already accomplish this?

Oh and if the question gets closed for not being programming related, please just leave a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its actually pretty easy to do, all you need is to write a utility that imports the entire structure into a document library, I've discovered all the links and paths in sandcastle output are relative, today I ran the import manually, and it worked like a charm.